# Running third-party command line software on AWS Lambda container image

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile

### Introduction

I'm new to AWS and I'm trying to run [Jellyfish](https://github.com/gmarcais/Jellyfish) on an AWS Lambda function with a python container image from an AWS base image.

### Context

I want to achieve this by installing the software from [source](https://github.com/gmarcais/Jellyfish#from-source) in my python container image (from AWS base image) and then uploading it to AWS ECR to be later used by a Lambda function.

My AWS architecture is:

- biome-test-bucket-out (AWS S3 bucket with trigger) -> Lambda function -> biome-test-bucket-jf (AWS S3 bucket)

First, to install it from source I downloaded the latest [release](https://github.com/gmarcais/Jellyfish/releases/tag/v2.3.0) .tar.gz file locally, then uncompressed it, and copied the contents in the container.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

# Copy contents from latest release
WORKDIR /jellyfish-2.3.0 
COPY ./jellyfish-2.3.0/ .
WORKDIR /

# Installing Jellyfish dependencies
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y gcc-c++
RUN yum install -y make

# Jellyfish installation (in /bin)
RUN jellyfish-2.3.0/configure --prefix=/bin
RUN make -j 4
RUN make install

RUN chmod -R 777 /bin

# Copy function code
COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
CMD [ "app.lambda_handler" ]
```

The installation folder is /bin because it's in $PATH so that way I can just run "jellyfish..." command.

My app.py looks like this:

```
import subprocess
import boto3
import logging
from pathlib import Path, PurePosixPath

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

print('Loading function')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # Declare buckets & get name of file
    bucket_in = "biome-test-bucket-out"
    bucket_out = "biome-test-bucket-jf"
    key = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]
    
    # Paths where files will be stored
    input_file_path = f"/tmp/{key}"
    file = Path(key).stem
    output_file_path = f"/tmp/{file}.jf"
    
    # Download file
    with open(input_file_path, 'wb') as f:
      s3.download_fileobj(bucket_in, key, f)

    # Run jellyfish with downloaded file
    command = f"/bin/jellyfish count -C -s 100M -m 20 -t 1 {input_file_path} -o {output_file_path}"
    logging.info(subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True))
    
    # Upload file to bucket
    try:
      with open(output_file_path, 'rb') as f:
        p = PurePosixPath(output_file_path).name
        s3.upload_fileobj(f, bucket_out, p)
        
    except Exception as e:
      logging.error(e)
      return False
    
    return 0
```

### Problem

If I build and run the image locally, everything works fine but once the image runs in Lambda I get this error:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file /bin/.libs/12-lt-jellyfish: Read-only file system

That file isn't there after the installation so I'm guessing that Jellyfish creates a new file in /bin/.libs/ when it's running and that file as only read permissions. I'm not sure how to tackle this, any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that only /tmp is writable, and its contents are deleted when the app runs. I found a workaround by installing in /tmp, and moving the contents out and back in at app runtime.

Dockerfile:

```py
WORKDIR /tmp 
COPY ./jellyfish-2.3.0/ .
RUN ./configure --prefix=/tmp
RUN make -j 4
RUN make install

WORKDIR /jf
RUN shopt -s dotglob && mv /tmp/* /jf
WORKDIR /
RUN chmod -R 777 /jf
```

app.py:

```py
# Move installation files back in tmp
shutil.copytree("/jf", "/tmp", copy_function=shutil.copy2,
                dirs_exist_ok=True)

# Run jellyfish with downloaded file
blast_command = "/tmp/bin/jellyfish count -C -s 100M -m 20 -t 1 "
command = f"{blast_command}{input_file_path} -o {output_file_path}"
logging.info(subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True))
```